# How can I publish an iOS library with AWS S3?

Tags: ios, amazon-s3, publishing

I'm trying to distribute an Android and iOS SDK through AWS S3 with credential authentication.
I've already successfully done it on the Android (that I've much more experience).

I've read these two awesome articles:

- 1 https://medium.com/streamroot-developers-blog/delivering-proprietary-libraries-via-amazon-s3-5aea2b7ccac8
- 2 https://medium.com/@porten/publishing-android-library-artifacts-to-amazon-s3-buckets-8db4231e844f

What I'm trying to do is something like the second link, that has the AWS authentication baked in.

I've achieved this goal on Android by creating a `Groovy` script that read the credentials from an encrypted file and communicate with the S3 bucket using `Gradle`.

**How can I achieve the same thing with iOS?**

> PS.The example on the first link didn't shown how to authenticate
> with the S3 bucket, I've assumed that is a public SDK